# Can landlords discriminate against potential tenants based on their current profession?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, discrimination, ohio

Simply enough, is it illegal to not rent to someone based on their current profession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost totally legal. Federal law prohibits discrimination on the basis of race, color, religion, national origin, sex, disability, and familial status, and Ohio law ([ORC 4112](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4112)) does extends the prohibition to ancestry and military status. So if the reason is "she's (not) a soldier", it's illegal, otherwise it is legal.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, great to know. I have made a habit of avoiding renting to lawyers. They seem like trouble.